# PHP Conditional Statement Inside / Nested in Single Quotes

Tags: php, conditional-operator

Apologies in advance on this one. But im stumped.

If i have single Quotes '' and put a PHP value inside those Quotes.

```
<?php $MyStatement = 'I want to echo '. $Value . ' now'; ?>
```

That is fine,

But if i want to do a conditional statement inside of quotes..

```
//Generated Config
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

$GeneratedConf ='if ($SomeProfile['SOMEVALUE_ENABLE']!=NULL) {
SOMEVALUEXML="'. $SomeProfile['SOMEVALUE_ENABLE'] .'"
}';

echo $GeneratedConf;
```

So if the $SOMEVALUE_ENABLE==NULL I want to hide whatever is inside { } operators..

Sorry for the late update

Apologies & Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary operator:

```
<?php $MyStatement = 'I want to echo '. (!empty($Value) ? $Value : 'Empty') . ' now'; ?>
```

Comment: But if you want to wrap the value and hide/show if it is ==NULL how would that work?

Thanks by the way!

Comment: wrap it by what? and by hiding you mean display nothing instead of `Empty`?  you can pretty much change your logic and avoid one liners like this if it's going to be complex. use a full `if-else` statement instead.

Comment: Yeah, Ideally that's what i want to do. But the if else statement needs to be inside the single quotes 'if ($Value!=NULL) { Show This } '

Comment: what is it that you want to hide specifically? the whole statement or just no `$Value`? by whole statement i mean the `I want to echo...` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<?php $MyStatement = 'I want to echo '. is_null($Value) ? 'Empty' : $Value . ' now'; ?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP 'try' this way?